# PHP Increment by Hours

Tags: php, datetime

We're using DateTime to loop through all of the days of the week and retrieve data on each day. I'd like to do the same thing, except get each hour range for the last 24 hours. Here is what we have for days per week:

```
$end = new DateTime();
$begin = new DateTime();
$begin->sub(new DateInterval("P7D"));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $date1=$date->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00";
    $date2=$date->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59";
}
```

I understand what P7D and P1D are doing, but how to I get an equivalent in hours? I can't find the documentation on these anywhere on php.net

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states:

> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is **preceded by the letter T**.

With that information, the interval specification for one hour should be:

```
PT1H
```

Comment: Yep I was missing the T. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[DateInterval::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)**

The Period Designators are below.

```
Y   years 
M   months
D   days
W   weeks. can not be combined with D.
H   hours
M   minutes
S   seconds
```

If you need an example, PHP.net has a [few comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php#example-2382) between period designators and Date Strings.